# Scrapy pipeline for MSSQL

Tags: python, sql, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing my own pipeline for Python scrapy:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import NotConfigured
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
import pymssql

from slybot.item import create_item_version

class SQLStore(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.conn = pymssql.connect(host='XXXXXX', user='sa', password='1timep', database='DBSample')
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    #log data to json file


def process_item(self, item, spider): 

    try:
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Movie(Description, Location,Title) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (item['Description'], item['Location'], item['Title']))
        self.conn.commit()

    except pymssql.Error, e:
        print ("error")

        return item
```

I am trying to insert the values into SQL server.

Below is my spider setting:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'slybot.dupefilter.SQLStore' : 100}
```

It is working fine. And when i submit my spider in Scrapyd i am seeing the below log file

```
2015-01-19 16:07:57+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: SQLStore
```

From the log file i am seeing that  my spider is using the `SQLStore` pipline.

But the **values are not loaded into SQL server** . I am able to see the content in the log files in the json format.

What went wrong. And what is the problem?

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is not properly indented. `process_item` is on the same level as `SQLStore` class definition, hence it is not a method of a class and is never called. Indent it:

```
import pymssql

from slybot.item import create_item_version


class SQLStore(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymssql.connect(host='XXXXXX', user='sa', password='1timep', database='DBSample')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Movie(Description, Location,Title) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                                (item['Description'], item['Location'], item['Title']))
            self.conn.commit()
        except pymssql.Error, e:
            print ("error")

        return item
```